# 'rethinking' package - making scale log-normal for gamma distribution

Tags: r, gamma-distribution

I am creating a model to predict the age of trees from their height using the rethinking package. In my data set, age is gamma distributed. To accommodate the gamma likelihood, I made this model using `map()`:

```
 fit2<- map(
  alist(
    age ~ dgamma2(mu, scale),
    log(mu) <- b + m*height,
    b ~ dnorm(16.3759, 10),
    m ~ dnorm(10.9808, 10),
    scale ~ dexp(2)
  ),
  data = d
)
```

However, I am concerned that "scale" isn't normally distributed and thus I can't use `extract.samples()` to sample the multi-dimensional posterior. I believe if I log the scale parameter, it becomes normal, and thus using `extract.samples()` will work.

How do I modify the code above to do this? I've seen this done in other examples with `dbetabinom()` but never with `dgamma2()`.

Comment: You should provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It should be [minimal, but complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your question should be clear and specific.

Answer (score 1):

The `scale` parameter is a positive number, so using exponential priors like `dexp(2)` makes sure that your model samples appropriate `scale` values. So your model should sample well and you shouldn't have problems using `extract.samples`.